# How to show error popup without changing label position?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Could you please tell me How to show error popup without changing label position .if you remove below line from component it shows label above input field.but when we added this line it take space and inserts between label and input field.

`

```
error={{ content: 'Please enter your first name', pointing: 'below' }}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-example-h4sql)

I tried to remove this using this CSS , but it change the position of all tooltip.

```
/* .error.field  .ui.pointing{
position: absolute;
top:-10px
} */
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS just needs to be a bit more specific to target the right class. Also, you should try to avoid globally targeting classes like this because you might unintentionally affect other mark-up that doesn't need this styling. Specificity is crucial.

Additionally, to make your styling more specific and less error-prone, give each `Form.Input` its own class.

### Example.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Form } from "semantic-ui-react";

const FormExampleFieldErrorLabel = () => (
  <Form>
    <Form.Input
      className="first-name"
      error={{ content: "Please enter your first name", pointing: "below" }}
      fluid
      label="First name"
      placeholder="First name"
    />

    <Form.Input
      className="last-name"
      error={{
        content: "Please enter your last name",
        pointing: "below"
      }}
      fluid
      label="Last name"
      placeholder="Last name"
    />

    <Form.Checkbox
      label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions"
      error={{
        content: "You must agree to the terms and conditions",
        pointing: "left"
      }}
    />
  </Form>
);

export default FormExampleFieldErrorLabel;
```

Then in our style-sheet, we will preface our selectors with the name of each class given to each `Form.Input` and override the styling providing by semantic-ui.

### styles.css

```
.first-name .pointing.below.label {
  top: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
}

.last-name .pointing.below.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 63px;
  left: -2px;
}
```

Also here is the working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-example-gcg0m).

Comment: @user944513 ah gotcha. Please see my updated solution and let me know if that works.

Comment: No ...because it is not a generic solution..ok but it works in this example